# Content Provider vs Remote Service to share db access between applications?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-service, android-contentprovider

- What are advantages and disadvantages of these two approaches (for
  android 4+)?
- Direct SQLite access vs Content Provider for big volume of data?

Thanks.

Comment: share DB access between what (users, devices, applications, ...)

Comment: Did you able to share your DB using remote services??

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523453/difference-between-android-service-and-content-provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this is really a bad question without any detail at all, I would like to give my thoughts about this.

We talked this a lot in our company. I was left with DB sharing code that is implemented using `AIDL` to share the data across processes. The problem was that it was too complicated. There were layers of classes to access to the Service to bind.

I removed those `AIDL` files and services and wrote a `ContentProvider`. I used the following library and it is really helpful. 
https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/ProviGen

We are going to give the DB access publicly to the 3rd party developers. So I also wrote an SDK that wraps the common operations of the database like `query/insert/delete`. They can for example just give an object to delete and the SDK convert that to a `DELETE` `ContentProvider` query. 
But we also expose the column names and `CONTENT_URI` for the DB to be used in `ContentLoader` which is really really good. And we use `Loaders` internally.